# Nginx not forwarding some requests

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, 502-error

I have a set-up where Nginx is set up as a reverse proxy forwarding requests with some pre-defined strings in URL to a checkout server. Other requests are sent to a load balancer which further distributes it to other web servers.
The problem is quite a few of my requests to checkout server end up in a 502. The strange part is I can see those requests in the Nginx log, but nowhere in the apache log on the checkout server. The requests before and after the 502s are visible on both logs.
Has anybody else faced this? Please help.

Thanks
Anand

Comment: You can try to [turning on debugging log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) in your nginx

Comment: Please edit your question to include the following: your configs, and your logs.

Comment: This mean nginx could not connect to your checkout server. What's your value for `proxy_connect_timeout`? Do you have some equipment between nginx and apache? Are you running firewall(s) somewhere? Did you make sure apache can still accept connections regarding to the traffic at the time of testing ? What's the max open files on your systems for your nginx user, and for apache one ? Please clarify with these elements and configuration parts.